# Add attachement to email

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

I have a request to create a `Get support` button in an application.
The button will have to open the `Lotus Notes` application(which is installed in a generic fixed location), to auto-complete the e-mail to, subject, body of the e-mail and also, the most important part, to add an attachement to the e-mail.

I managed to open the Lotus Notes with the fields completed with the command:
`mailto:support_adress@domain.com?subject=First%20Email%20&body=this is the body`

The problem is with the attachement. Due to security concerns, `mailto` doesn't support attachements.

So the question is, can I do it with an `Lotus Notes Script`( which can be executed from my application)?
If yes, can anyone guide me to some usefull informations or examples to start learning to create a script which would do it?

Comment: Hi, some keywords are lotusscript mail com, notesrichtextitem embedobject, notesuiworkspace, and notesdocument

Comment: @umeli At the moment I am not even sure how this script will be executed, so I will go from the begining. Do you think it's realizable? Should I invest time in this or abort mission?

Comment: Why do you say you have to open the Lotus Notes application? The entire job can be done with the Notes COM classes without the need to start the client, and without any need for the user to click a button to send the final message. If the user needs to provide input, you can code that in a dialogue in your own application and add that to the message body.

Comment: Hi, What kind of application, are we talking about ? Custom Windows Client? Browser? If it's a kind of windows application, you can use the COM. If it's a browser then it's getting tricky....

Comment: @RichardSchwartz There is no need for user input and of course I can program it in my own application

Comment: @umeli Desktop application, like an IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with LotusScript:

- get [user's mail database](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_OPENMAIL_METHOD.html)
- [create a new document in backend](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_CREATEDOCUMENT_METHOD.html)
- add fields "SendTo" and "Subject"
- [create RichText field](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_CREATERICHTEXTITEM_METHOD.html) "Body" and attach file to it
- [open document in UI](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_EDITDOCUMENT_METHOD.html)

Comment: One more question, how do I interact with the script? I mean after I will start and learn how to create the script and follow the steps from the links(which are pretty straightforward, thank you for that), what will be it's extension? Can it be executed like an exe or something?

Comment: Is your application able to use COM/OLE? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_USING_NOTES_CLASSES_IN_VISUAL_BASIC.html

Comment: I assume yes, it's a Java based application, so it should be

Comment: Should be possible with Java. Use e.g. JACOB http://danadler.com/jacob/ or class org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleAutomation.

Comment: Thank you, I think for the moment this answers my questions.